# Making PHP variable links row specific

Tags: php, hyperlink, html-table

I have created an HTML table that posts query data from SQL. It looks like this:

`John Doe  | 52 | 40 | (checkbox)`

`Jane Doe  | 52 | 40 | (checkbox)`

`Tim Rose | 52 | 40 | (checkbox)`

I need John Doe's link to display HIS time entries, Jane Doe to display hers, and so on. Here is my code so far:

```
    $x = 0; 
while( $client_display_timecards = mysql_fetch_assoc( $res_client_display_timecards ) )
{
    $lname = $client_display_timecards['ContractorLName'];
    $fname = $client_display_timecards['ContractorFName'];
    $contractorid = $client_display_timecards['ContractorID'];
    $totalhours = $client_display_timecards['SUM(TimeCards.HoursTotal)'];
    $week = $client_display_timecards['Week'];

    $current_cards[$x] = array(
    'contractorfname' => "$fname",
    'contractorlname' => "$lname",
    'contractorid' => "$contractorid",
    'week' => "$week"
    );


echo <<<END
      <tr>
        <td class="cell_client_left" align="center">$fname $lname</td>
        <td class="cell_client" align="center"><a href="week.php">$week</a></td>
        <td class="cell_client" align="center">$totalhours</td>
        <td class="cell_client_right" align="center">
            <input type="checkbox" name="approve$x" value="$x" />
        </td>

      </tr>
END;
    ++$x;
}
```

I just need each link to reflect the information in each individual row because right now, it's just making every query result a link to the same place. Is there some sort of loop I need to put in there? Can I associate one cell to the one to its left?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are asking for. What "link" are you trying to create; one to the user profile, what exactly?

Comment: what does your mysql query look like? what's your table structure?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct for what I assume you are trying to do. The problem may exist in your SQL statement, or possibly somewhere else.

Does the output display correctly? FName/LName/Week/Total

You reference a link, but I am not sure what you mean here. Are you referring to the checkbox being submitteD?

Comment: I need $week in each row to be a different link. It would help if I know what I was talking about. Haha.


$week in the first row should show the week for John Doe.
$week in the second row should show the week for Jane Doe.


...


Does that make sense?

Comment: If you are linking to another page (week.php) then you could pass the name or contractorid to the page via get...i.e: a href="week.php?id=$contractorid" and then in week.php connect to SQL and select data for that week. Can we see week.php to have a better understanding? This is another page, or a popup/ajax call?

Comment: week.php is another file. How would the link know what contractor ID to pull, though? The variable is a link and it works inside of a loop, filling every row in my HTML table with different info, but making each instance of $week go to the same place...

Comment: To David: This is a link, btw...  <a href="week.php">$week</a>

Comment: No ideas? I'm kind of disappointed that the only responses I've received have been expressions of confusion. If you know PHP, the example code I've provided should be pretty clear...